# List files in a folder that match permission settings

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions

Is there a way I can write a script, preferably in PHP, that will list only the files in a folder and all subfolders that match certain permission settings?

I need to check permissions on files within a lot of folders and subfolders, and want to find a way to speed up that process!

So a PHP script that essentially does the following, for example:

"list all files in the directory and subdirectories that have permissions 777"

So only files with permissions 777 would then be listed.

I know how to make a PHP script that lists all files, but struggling with the condition to list only files that match the permission settings.

Comment: You can check the file permissions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

Comment: I used the information in the link above provided by Fracsi to do this, so if you want to make this a proper answer then I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$list = `find . -perm 777`
?>
```

Comment: How would I use this to have a script sitting on my webspace that I can call, and will print out a list of all matching files to a page?

Comment: I modified my answer accordingly; with `$list` you can do anything possible in PHP.